# Rviz on Odroid - undefined references to Ogre namespace

Tags: rviz, ros-hydro, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, ogre

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a Odroid-X2, which is a ARM platform, and I'm trying to install rviz on it (yes I know it can be a heavy task to a ARM board but it serves as testing for now). I have Linaro 12.11 installed with ROS Hydro. When trying to catkin_make my ws I get only the following errors, related to Ogre:

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/76a1dad3d5c06b63435441bb343c731b

I have ogre installed by debian packages, namely libogre-1.7.4, libogre-1.7.4-dbg, libogre-dev, libogre-perl and ogre-utils. Is there something missing here? Any tips?

Thanks in advance! Best regards

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/174748/rviz-on-odroid---undefined-references-to-ogre-namespace/) by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) on ROS Answers with karma: 180 on 2014-06-24

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Never mind! It was solved after a clean install ;)

Then, just have to apply what's in this topic: http://answers.ros.org/question/52098/unable-to-compile-rviz-on-ubuntu-armhf/

---

Originally posted by [TSC](https://answers.ros.org/users/8171/tsc/) with karma: 210 on 2014-07-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0